# Azure Active Directory B2C Phone Signups issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup a User Flow and Phone Signups/Signin. After entering my phone number on Login Page, i have being redirected to enter Country and Phone number again. I want to remove this setup. Please Help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI6Pk.png

Answer (score 0):

No, you couldn't remove it, the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication#phone-sign-in-experience) are designed by Azure. Try to feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Xafar. You can use custom policy option also and here is example - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/scenarios/phone-number-passwordless

Comment: Just to note. If you want to "customise" the country codes, you can do that as well - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/customising-the-phone-drop-down-in-azure-ad-b2c-774656391d2d

Comment: The problem is i want this to be a two step process, i dont want to let users enter phone number twice

Comment: Jit_MSFT has referred to use custom policy. You could custom to set country code and phone number on one page, but you could not skip setting country code.

Comment: How to put Country Code and Phone number on Login page, please help